# How to convert XML data into row column data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, types, row, calculated-columns

I have a requirement where I have XML data in database, which I need to pull in the form of row and Column from database. My XML is like

```
<Equipment>
<EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentType>E</EquipmentType><MfgName>APPLE iPH564WHT</MfgName><Model>885909600205</Model><ActDate>10/26/2012</ActDate><CancelDate />
</EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentType>E</EquipmentType><MfgName>SAMSUNG D710 HANDSET KIT</MfgName><Model>SPHD710KIT</Model><ActDate>09/04/2012</ActDate><CancelDate>10/01/2012</CancelDate>
</EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentType>E</EquipmentType><MfgName>BLACKBERRY 9670 PURPLE</MfgName><Model>SPRIM9670P</Model><ActDate>08/22/2012</ActDate><CancelDate>08/25/2012</CancelDate>
</EquipmentRecord>
</Equipment>
```

And I want data to be pulled up like

```
EquipmentType   MfgName                 Model           ActDate     CancelDate
E             APPLE iPH564WHT           885909600205    10/26/2012  
E             SAMSUNG D710 HANDSET KIT  SPHD710KIT      09/04/2012  10/01/2012
E             BLACKBERRY 9670 PURPLE    SPRIM9670P      08/22/2012  08/25/2012
```

is there any simple way to this in SQL server?

I tried and it worked

```
DECLARE @doc XML
SET @doc = 'above XML'  

CREATE TABLE #EquipmentType (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), EquipmentType varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #EquipmentType(EquipmentType)
SELECT EquipmentDetails.value('.','varchar(100)') as EquipmentType
FROM @doc.nodes('/Equipment/EquipmentRecord/EquipmentType/.') Equipment(EquipmentDetails)

CREATE TABLE #MfgName (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), MfgName varchar(500))
INSERT INTO #MfgName(MfgName)
SELECT EquipmentDetails.value('.','varchar(500)') as MfgName
FROM @doc.nodes('/Equipment/EquipmentRecord/MfgName/.') Equipment(EquipmentDetails)

CREATE TABLE #Model (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Model varchar(500))
INSERT INTO #Model(Model)
SELECT EquipmentDetails.value('.','varchar(500)') as Model
FROM @doc.nodes('/Equipment/EquipmentRecord/Model/.') Equipment(EquipmentDetails)

CREATE TABLE #ActDate (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ActDate varchar(500))
INSERT INTO #ActDate(ActDate)
SELECT EquipmentDetails.value('.','varchar(500)') as ActDate
FROM @doc.nodes('/Equipment/EquipmentRecord/ActDate/.') Equipment(EquipmentDetails)

CREATE TABLE #CancelDate (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), CancelDate varchar(500))
INSERT INTO #CancelDate(CancelDate)
SELECT EquipmentDetails.value('.','varchar(500)') as CancelDate
FROM @doc.nodes('/Equipment/EquipmentRecord/CancelDate/.') Equipment(EquipmentDetails)

SELECT EquipmentType,MfgName,Model,ActDate,CancelDate 
FROM #EquipmentType ET
Inner Join #MfgName MN ON (ET.ID = MN.ID)
Inner Join #Model MO ON (MN.ID = MO.ID)
Inner Join #ActDate AD ON (MO.ID = AD.ID)
Inner Join #CancelDate CD ON (AD.ID = CD.ID)

DROP TABLE #EquipmentType
DROP TABLE #MfgName
DROP TABLE #Model
DROP TABLE #ActDate
DROP TABLE #CancelDate
```

but I want a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OPENXML; be sure to remove the document reference (sp_xml_removedocument) to avoid memory leaks:

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<Equipment>
<EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentType>E</EquipmentType><MfgName>APPLE iPH564WHT</MfgName><Model>885909600205</Model><ActDate>10/26/2012</ActDate><CancelDate />
</EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentType>E</EquipmentType><MfgName>SAMSUNG D710 HANDSET KIT</MfgName><Model>SPHD710KIT</Model><ActDate>09/04/2012</ActDate><CancelDate>10/01/2012</CancelDate>
</EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentRecord>
<EquipmentType>E</EquipmentType><MfgName>BLACKBERRY 9670 PURPLE</MfgName><Model>SPRIM9670P</Model><ActDate>08/22/2012</ActDate><CancelDate>08/25/2012</CancelDate>
</EquipmentRecord>
</Equipment>'


DECLARE @iX INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @ix output, @x


SELECT EquipmentType, MfgName, Model, ActDate, CancelDate = NULLIF(CancelDate, '1900-01-01')
FROM OPENXML(@iX, '//EquipmentRecord', 2) 
WITH (EquipmentType varchar(10),
        MfgName VARCHAR(100),
        Model VARCHAR(100),
        ActDate DATE,
        CancelDate date)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @iX
```

Comment: This worked thanks. Trying to understand more on OPENXML. Thanks for knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

The following query should work:

```
declare @X xml = 'your xml';

select  x.r.value('(EquipmentType)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [EquipmentType],
    x.r.value('(MfgName)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as [MfgName],
    x.r.value('(Model)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as [Model],
    x.r.value('(ActDate)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as [ActDate],
    x.r.value('(CancelDate)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as [CancelDate]
from    @X.nodes('/Equipment/EquipmentRecord') as x(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I got opportunity to work on same requirement. The following query should work:

```
                DECLARE @xmlData xml = '<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><row><EmpId>13</EmpId><EmpName>3372</EmpName></row></root> */';
            DECLARE @allCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
                    @finalQry  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

            --Create temp table
            CREATE table #tempTable
                ([Value] varchar(50), [ColumnName] varchar(50));

            --Get data from xml tag and insert data in temp table object 
            Insert into #tempTable SELECT 
            x.y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ColumnValue,
                x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ColumnName
                FROM @xmlData.nodes('//*[text()]') AS x(y)

            --Prepare rows into columns 
            select @allCols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                                from #tempTable
                                group by ColumnName

                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,1,'')

            set @finalQry = N'SELECT ' + @allCols + N' from 
                         (
                            select value, ColumnName
                            from #tempTable
                        ) x
                        pivot 
                        (
                            max(value)
                            for ColumnName in (' + @allCols + N')
                        ) p '

            exec sp_executesql @finalQry;

            drop table #tempTable
```