# Read key Value pair XML from nvarchar in query which returns value in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, parsexml

I want to read an XML nvarchar column:

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="costcenter">
      <value>
        <List>
          <String>R03e</String>
          <String>L07e</String>
        </List>
      </value>
    </entry>
    <entry key="department" value="Information Technology"/>
    <entry key="email" value="Paul.Walker@demoexample.com"/>
    <entry key="employeeId" value="1a2a3b4d"/>
    <entry key="firstName" value="Paul"/>
    <entry key="fullName" value="Paul.Walker"/>
    <entry key="inactiveIdentity" value="FALSE"/>
    <entry key="lastName" value="Walker"/>
    <entry key="location" value="Austin"/>
    <entry key="managerId" value="1a2c3a4d"/>
    <entry key="region" value="Americas"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

I want results in columns like this:

```
costSenter | department | email | employeeId | firstName | lastName | location | managerId | region
```

Comment: Check if this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096527/how-to-convert-xml-data-into-row-column-data-in-sql-server#answer-23097475

Comment: "clob" is an oracle datatype, correct? If so, why tag of SQL Server?

Comment: @SMor yes its nvarchar(max) . for general understanding i said it clob.

Comment: @DaleK i tried whatever i could find here. but count find any parser which was for XML format which i have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nodes` xml method (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)) to shred your xml, apply attribute filtering and extract the information from `value` attribute.

You can use `cross apply` to extend this operation to all the `<entry>` tags

Here is a basic query that you can use as a starting point:

```
declare @src nvarchar(max)='
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="costcenter">
      <value>
        <List>
          <String>R03e</String>
          <String>L07e</String>
        </List>
      </value>
    </entry>
    <entry key="department" value="Information Technology"/>
    <entry key="email" value="Paul.Walker@demoexample.com"/>
    <entry key="employeeId" value="1a2a3b4d"/>
    <entry key="firstName" value="Paul"/>
    <entry key="fullName" value="Paul.Walker"/>
    <entry key="inactiveIdentity" value="FALSE"/>
    <entry key="lastName" value="Walker"/>
    <entry key="location" value="Austin"/>
    <entry key="managerId" value="1a2c3a4d"/>
    <entry key="region" value="Americas"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>'

;with x as
(
    select  cast(@src as xml) as attributes
)
select 
      costcenter.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as costcenter
    , department.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as department
    , email.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as email
    , employeeId.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as employeeId
    , firstName.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as firstName
    , fullName.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as fullName
    , inactiveIdentity.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as inactiveIdentity
    , lastName.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as lastName
    , loc.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as [location]
    , managerID.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as managerId
    , region.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as region
 
from x
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "costcenter"]/value') costcenter(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "department"]/@value') department(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "email"]/@value') email(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "employeeId"]/@value') employeeId(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "firstName"]/@value') firstName(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "fullName"]/@value') fullName(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "inactiveIdentity"]/@value') inactiveIdentity(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "lastName"]/@value') lastName(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "location"]/@value') loc(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "managerId"]/@value') managerID(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "region"]/@value') region(s)
```

Results:

[image]

*P.S. In the future please follow the advice you got in the comments: post the code you have tried so far highlighting the problems you were unable to solve.*