# How do I extract a value from an XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a column SCORERESULTS in table CSE_ARCHIVEDCREDITSCORE.

Score results is an XML column.

```
<ScoringEngine>
  <Profile id="Navigation" version="1" num="4" uniqueId="8bcf8a8b9efc4e5dad1d87510cfe6a64">
.
.
.
    <Tool id="Payment To Income Ratio" version="1" old_id="Pmt_To_Income">
      <Rule id="PaymentIncomeRatio" version="1" old_id="PTI">
        <Row uniqueId="0fb11598c4224e4c97cf2afcc4e34b54" order="6" id="0">
          <Column order="1" op="RNG2" start="0.18" end="0.2" title="Payment To Income Ratio">0.190325139</Column>
          <Action name="Record Value" value="1.42085235920852" fieldName="LO_R_PMT_TO_INCOME" />
        </Row>
      </Rule>
      <RecordedValue>
        <Value value="1.42085235920852" fieldName="LO_R_PMT_TO_INCOME" />
      </RecordedValue>
    </Tool>
    <Tool id="RecentLoans" version="2">
      <Rule id="RecentLoans" version="2" old_id="RecentLoans" />
    </Tool>
.
.
.
  </Profile>
</ScoringEngine>
```

I am trying to get the value 0.190325139 out of the XML line:               `<Column order="1" op="RNG2" start="0.18" end="0.2" title="Payment To Income Ratio">0.190325139</Column>`
I am clueless on how to pull it.  I'm not familiar with XML, or really how to navigate it well.

Comment: Hope this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096527/how-to-convert-xml-data-into-row-column-data-in-sql-server#answer-23097475

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately it doesn't really help me.  I've figured out that I need to use scoreresults.value() to access the XML.  My larger problem is I don't know enough about navigating XML to actually return the portion I actually want.

Comment: Will each xml will only have 1 tag with name <Column>?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below query. Make sure the column SCORERESULTS is of type XML.

```
SELECT SCORERESULTS.value('(ScoringEngine/Profile/Tool/Rule/Row/Column)[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS result
FROM CSE_ARCHIVEDCREDITSCORE
```

If the column is not of type XML use the below query

```
SELECT CAST(SCORERESULTS AS XML).value('(ScoringEngine/Profile/Tool/Rule/Row/Column)[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS result
FROM CSE_ARCHIVEDCREDITSCORE
```

Comment: That almost works.  I mis-understood your question about the <column> tag.  There's not one per XML, but there is one per <Tool> tag, with the tool containing different variables.

Thank you for the help you've been providing.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing now?

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  There are multiple <column> tags, one per <tool> so I just need to narrow down to the correct tool 
Payment To Income Ratio

Comment: I kept plugging away and was able to get to where I needed.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobertRichardson, glad that the solution was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach.

XPath predicate is filtering out not needed `<Tool>` elements.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata)
VALUES
(N'<ScoringEngine>
    <Profile id="Navigation" version="1" num="4"
             uniqueId="8bcf8a8b9efc4e5dad1d87510cfe6a64">
        <Tool id="Payment To Income Ratio" version="1" old_id="Pmt_To_Income">
            <Rule id="PaymentIncomeRatio" version="1" old_id="PTI">
                <Row uniqueId="0fb11598c4224e4c97cf2afcc4e34b54" order="6"
                     id="0">
                    <Column order="1" op="RNG2" start="0.18" end="0.2"
                            title="Payment To Income Ratio">0.190325139</Column>
                    <Action name="Record Value" value="1.42085235920852"
                            fieldName="LO_R_PMT_TO_INCOME"/>
                </Row>
            </Rule>
            <RecordedValue>
                <Value value="1.42085235920852" fieldName="LO_R_PMT_TO_INCOME"/>
            </RecordedValue>
        </Tool>
        <Tool id="RecentLoans" version="2">
            <Rule id="RecentLoans" version="2" old_id="RecentLoans"/>
        </Tool>
    </Profile>
</ScoringEngine>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT tbl.ID
    , c.value('(Rule/Row/Column/text())[1]','DECIMAL(10,8)') AS [value]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/ScoringEngine/Profile/Tool[@id="Payment To Income Ratio"]') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+
| ID |   value    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 0.19032514 |
+----+------------+
```