# Extract xml value from table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract value from xml in table.PFB sample xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfKeyValue xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <KeyValue>
        <Key>[#Id#]</Key>
        <Value>354005</Value>
</ArrayOfKeyValue>
```

I am trying below script and it is not working.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(([KeyWordValues]) AS ntext) AS XML).value('(/ArrayOfKeyValue/KeyValue[1])', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM 
    Table
```

I'm getting this error :

> Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Please note XML is saved as `varchar` in the database.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XQuery \[value()\]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic \*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940566/xquery-value-value-requires-a-singleton-or-empty-sequence-found-oper)

Comment: Did you try searching for the error first? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940566/xquery-value-value-requires-a-singleton-or-empty-sequence-found-oper

Comment: update your path `(ArrayOfKeyValue/KeyValue/Key)[1]`, check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63285429/how-do-i-extract-a-value-from-an-xml-column-in-sql-server/63286171#answers-header

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for help. I got it working.

```
 SELECT cast(cast(([KeyWordValues]) as ntext) as 
 xml).value('(/ArrayOfKeyValue/KeyValue/Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
 FROM Table
```

Comment: `cast(([KeyWordValues]) as ntext` this is not required, you can directly cast to XML as `cast([KeyWordValues] as xml)`